# How do I add variables to my regression solely when another variable is a specific value?

Tags: r

My dataset contains R&D expenses for the same company for several periods: -3 to +3. I use this fixed effects linear model:

```
m5a <- felm(ihs(RD_expenses) ~ merger_it_pre1 + merger_it + merger_it_post1 + merger_it_post2 + merger_it_post3 + factor(year),
           data = TandC,
           subset = RD_expenses > pcts[1] & RD_expenses < pcts[2])
```

Now I want to add a covariate for RD expenses but only when the period is -1. The period variable is another column in the same dataset.

Any ideas how I can do this? I tried to add `ihs(RD_expenses)if(period = -1))` to the model but this did not work. I get the error: unexpected if.

I'm quite new to R so if someone could help me out that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Add it as a column in your data. `TandC$rd_expenses_period_neg1 = ifelse(TandC$period == -1, TandC$RD_expenses, 0)`

Comment: Thanks! But I get this error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, rd_expenses_pre3, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 26179`

Comment: Can you share  little bit of sample data in your question? `dput(TandC[1:5, ])` will give a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows of `TandC` including all class and structure information.

Comment: Your first suggestion worked! I forgot to include the period variable in the dataset :)